# Retrieve Used and New Items, detecting their condition - Amazon-MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

We allready get a list of our Products through the Amazon MWS API, with the ReportTyp `_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_`.
Probelm we have is, that we cant see if the product is `NEW` or `USED`.
And i also dont know any report with whom i could do that.
Do you know any solution, which gives me the opportunity to detect, wether an SKU is listed under `NEW` or under `USED`?

Thanks in adcanve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following way to go, for this problem.
You will need the `Amazon MWS Product API` with the ReportTyp `GetMyPriceForSKU`. There you will find the section `condition` and `subCondition`.